# RxSwift protocol and concrete types

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I'm having trouble with a `BehaviorRelay` that has a protocol type and using it on concrete types. Here's my code:

```
protocol Item {

    var title: { get }

}

struct Can: Item {

    let title = "Can"

}

let canRelay = BehaviorRelay<Can?>(value: nil)

func handle(item: BehaviorRelay<Item?>) {
    // do something with item here
}

handle(item: canRelay) // can't do this?
```

I assumed I would be able to call `handle(item:)` but it's not the case because the arguments don't match. I get that they don't match, but `Can` is a type of `Item` so shouldn't this be possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Can` may be a subtype of `Item`, but `BehaviorRelay<Can>` is *not* a subtype of `BehaviorRelay<Item>`.

Also, you should not be passing BehaviorRelays around in code. Pass Observables instead.

Once you know these two rules, you end up with:

```swift
func handle(item: Observable<Item?>) {
    // do something with item here
}

handle(item: canRelay.map { $0 })
```

Comment: Ok, I get about not passing around `BehaviourRelay`s but can I just not do what I'm trying to do then with a protocol and a concrete type?

Comment: I don't know what exactly you are trying to do, but you can use protocols and concrete types as I showed in the answer, you just have to map from `Observable<Can>` to `Observable<Item>`. (Note, you would have to do the same thing with arrays. `[Can]` is not a subtype of `[Item]`.)

Comment: Thanks! Also do you have more reading about not passing BehaviorRelays around over Observables?

Comment: ["Subjects provide a convenient way to poke around Rx, however they are not recommended for day to day use."](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/02_KeyTypes.html#KeyTypes) (A Relay is a kind of Subject.)